# Find and count compressed files by extension

Tags: bash, unix

I have a bash script that counts compressed files by file extension and prints the count.

```
#!/bin/bash

FIND_COMPRESSED=$(find . -type f | sed -e 's/.*\.//' | sort | uniq -c | sort -rn | grep -Ei '(deb|tgz|tar|gz|zip)$')

COUNT_LINES=$($FIND_COMPRESSED | wc -l)

if [[ $COUNT_LINES -eq 0 ]]; then
    echo "No archived files found!"
else
    echo "$FIND_COMPRESSED"
fi
```

However, the script works only if there are **NO** files with `.deb .tar .gz .tgz .zip`.

If there are some, say `test.zip` and `test.tar` in the current folder, I get this error:

```
./arch.sh: line 5: 1: command not found
```

Yet, if I copy the contents of the `FIND_COMPRESSED` variable into the `COUNT_LINES`, all works fine.

```
#!/bin/bash

FIND_COMPRESSED=$(find . -type f | sed -e 's/.*\.//' | sort | uniq -c | sort -rn | grep -Ei '(deb|tgz|tar|gz|zip)$')

COUNT_LINES=$(find . -type f | sed -e 's/.*\.//' | sort | uniq -c | sort -rn | grep -Ei '(deb|tgz|tar|gz|zip)$'| wc -l)

if [[ $COUNT_LINES -eq 0 ]]; then
    echo "No archived files found!"
else
    echo "$FIND_COMPRESSED"
fi
```

What am I missing here?

Comment: Your problem can be reduced to `foo=$(echo "hello, world"); count=$($foo | wc -l)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So when you do that variable like that, it tries to execute it like a command, which is why it fails when it has contents. When it's empty, `wc` simply returns 0 and it marches on.

Thus, you need to change that line to this:

```
COUNT_LINES=$(echo $FIND_COMPRESSED | wc -l)
```

But, while we're at it, you can also simplify the other line with something like this:

```
FIND_COMPRESSED=$(find . -type f -iname "*deb" -or -iname "*tgz" -or -iname "*tar*") #etc
```

Comment: That did it! Thanks for the extra tip.

Answer (score 0):

you can do

```
mapfile FIND_COMPRESSED < <(find . -type f -regextype posix-extended -regex ".*(deb|tgz|tar|gz|zip)$" -exec bash -c '[[ "$(file {})" =~ compressed ]] && echo {}' \;)
COUNT_LINES=${#FIND_COMPRESSED[@]}
```